# Adding "external" features to Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn

I'd like to compose a pipleline for textual text. However there is an
extra step in the pipeline where "external" features are added. These
features are stored in external database and are accessed by document id
(the row number in the input).

The custom pipeline stage comes after a tfidf step. Meaning the input to the
stage will be a sparse matrix. Is there a way for me to pass the indices in
the input matrix as well? Or maybe a generic way to pass some metadata between
pipeline stages?

Note that the input to the pipeline is selected by GridSearchCV.

I saw the [Feature Union with Heterogeneous Data Sources](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#example-hetero-feature-union-py), but fail to see how to apply it to my situation since I can't compute the features from the input to the stage.